# How to mutate a column in tidyverse for 'if text contains text string'

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, tidyverse

How do I edit this code to replace `==` with if the Species contains `%setosa%`

```
new_iris <- iris %>% 
   mutate(flag = ifelse(Species == "setosa", 1, 0)  # add a new column
          )
```

Comment: If speed is a concern, be sure to set `fixed = T` when using `grepl`. If you are searching for literal text (not using regex) it'll make it a little bit quicker.

Comment: Super! In my database I to have search for the string "2-bed-2-bath,3corners"...is it possible to search this string as it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `%like%` from `data.table`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
iris %>% 
     mutate( flag = as.integer(Species %like% "setosa") )
```

Comment: Super!It works. In my database I have search for the string "2-bed-2-bath,3corners"...isit possible

Comment: @TRex  Thanks.  Have you tried `as.integer(columnName %like%  "2-bed-2-bath,3corners")`

Comment: Lastly I see that "2-bed-2-bath,3corners" is not the same as "2-Bed-2-Bath,3Corners". How can I ignore the case sensitivity

Comment: Is `tolower()` sufficient?

Comment: OK...makes sense. I'll try that. I've been trying ignore.case = TRUE. Not sure why it does not work

Answer (score 3):

To stay in the tidyverse you could use stringr.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

 iris %>%
    mutate(flag = str_detect(Species, "setosa"))
```